# Menu wont draw and gives error

Tags: c#

Im trying to get it to draw the menu after you choice an option so you can easily navigate menus.
I am getting the error 'The name DrawMainMenu does not exist in the current context.

```
using System;

{
    class Menu
    {
        public void DrawMainMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trial");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("               MasterMind's Main Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("                    1: Play");
            Console.WriteLine("                    2: Help");
            Console.WriteLine("                    0: Exit");
            string userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
            if (userInput == "2")
            {
                DrawMainMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("This is not a number 2");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You defined `DrawMainMenu` as a method of the `Menu` class, it's not a global function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrawMainMenu is only available via the Menu class.  In order to reference it outside of the Menu class, you'll need to instantiate a new Menu() and call it as a property, like this:

```
var menu = new Menu();
menu.DrawMainMenu();
```

Alternatively, if you add the `static` keyword to the Menu class (and DrawMainMenu method), you can call it without instantiating a new Menu object, like this:

```
Menu.DrawMainMenu();
```